# Comparing two Lists in Prolog, To Determine if the Equal Elements of both lists are the Same Count

Tags: list, prolog, counting

Im just starting to learn Polog, and I have to do following things
first:
I have to write a predicate, that checks if a list A contains only some of those elements that B has. (A=[a,b] B=[a,b,c] is true), I done that, but I also have to determine if the equal elements of both lists are the same count.

```
Example:
A = [b,b,c,c]     (b and c is member of B so its true)
B = [a,b,b,c,c,d,f,g]   
<--would be true
```

I have written the first part, but I still have to check the count. **BUT I can't use sorting and numbers to check it :[**  teacher suggested using select, but it's optional

second:
I have to add another expression to predicate, that checks if a list C contains only some of those elements that B has (identical to previous task). (C=[a,b] B=[a,b,c] is true) (ive done it already),  but I also have to check if the elements of B show up 2x times in C.

```
Example:
A = [b,b,c,c]
B = [a,b,b,c,c,d,e,f,g] 
C = [b,b,b,b,c,c,c,c] /or/ C=[a,a,b,b,b,b]
would be true.
```

EDIT1: And the code I have written so far is:

```
subset([ ],_). 
subset([H|T],List) :-       
    member(H,List),     
    subset(T,List).     



p(A,B,C) :-                    %this is the predicate in which I have to 
    subset(A,B),               %compile everything together
    subset(C,B).
```

Comment: Can you post the code you have already written?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first one can be accomplished by removing every element on B as they appear in A, and returning what is left, then we check that the remainder does not contain any element that is in A (I.E. they are the same count).

```
dontIntersect(L1,L2) :-
    intersection(L1,L2,[]).

subset_2([], R, R).

subset_2([H | T], List, R):-
    select(H, List, NewList),
    subset_2(T, NewList, R).

subset(L1, L2):-
    subset_2(L1,L2,Remainder),
    dontIntersect(L1,Remainder).
```

The second one is very similar except for the fact that we remove two elements from the list at once.

```
dontIntersect(L1,L2) :-
    intersection(L1,L2,[]).

subset_2([], R, R).

subset_2([H | T], List, R):-
    select(H, List, NewList1),
    select(H, NewList1, NewList2),
    subset_2(T, NewList2, R).

subset(L1, L2):-
    subset_2(L1,L2,Remainder),
    dontIntersect(L1,Remainder).
```

Comment: Thanks Rodolfo! That was exactly how I imagined to solve this problem, but couldn't quite put it in code yet. I've upvoted your comment, but it will show up only when I reach 15 reputation :] But im having an issue with second part of code, Ill try to explain it in edit, just a sec:

Comment: `[trace] 69 ?- subset3x([a,b],[a,a,b,b,c]).
       ...
               Exit: (10) select([], [b, c], [b,c]) ? creep **
     ..      
        Call: (9) lists:intersection([a, b], [b, c], []) ? creep
  ** Fail: (9) lists:intersection([a, b], [b, c], []) ? **
`

I highlighted the problem, It takes an empty list at that stage, so some symbols get caught in the reminder. Im currently thinking how to fix this issue :D

Comment: NEVERMIND, sorry, it all works, I had made mistake when I integrated your code. 
Anyway, thank you alot buddy :]

Comment: Glad to be of help!